# TypeError: decoding str is not supported(when trying to import feedparser in python program)

Tags: python

I'm testing out my Python video game search engine that I created importing feedparser, but when I try to debug these first 3 lines:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> url = "http://newyork.craigslist.org/vga?format=rss"
>>> f = feedparser.parse(url)
```

from the command line, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/feedparser-5.1.3-py3.4.egg/feedparser.py", line 3966, in parse
    f.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/feedparser-5.1.3-py3.4.egg/feedparser.py", line 3768, in convert_to_utf8
    msg = 'no Content-type specified'
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

I installed feedparser though so maybe I'm not importing that module correctly. But in any case, I'd appreciate any help that you can give me.

Comment: I'd guess this is because feedparser just uses 2to3 to install under python 3, but still replies on ugly hacks of calling `.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')` on arbitrary things without any real reason to think they're bytestrings. You might try passing in the url as a `bytes` object instead of a regular str, but that may break other things.

Comment: Do you know of any parsing modules that are Python3 compatible?

Comment: works fine for me, what  version are you using?

Comment: Do you mean version of feedparser? In that case, it's version 5.1.3

Comment: scratch that I can see the version

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: I used `pip install feedparser`. But when I ran my program from the terminal, I got the same error, so maybe it's a problem with feedparser itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71795/discussion-between-brown1001-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using feedparser 5.2.1 (from `pip3 install feedparser`) and the bug seems fixed.